# How to execute build.xml using jar managed by Maven?

Tags: java, maven, ant

Our project uses Maven to manage the dependent Jar collection, and we use Ant to build the project. Now I have a question when I'm writing `build.xml`; I cannot easily get the dependent Jar set when compiling Java source code because they are stored in the user's repository. So I was wondering if there is any better way to use the Maven plugin to automactically load these jars when executing the `build.xml` file.

Comment: Have you considered building with maven only?  It is quite good at compiling.

Comment: This is a Java EE project, I need to not only compile java source code but do another things like copying files, inlcuding CSS, images, JSP, JS,etc. I'm not sure if maven can do this?

Comment: Yep, it can.  Check out the war/ear/assembly/resource plugins (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/index.html).  Where I work we use maven (exclusively) to build over 100 JEE projects.

Comment: If you're just using Maven to manage jars, why not switch to Ivy which integrates quite nicely with Ant, and has the same dependency resolving prowess as Maven. Heck, it can even use the same Maven repos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better way is only using maven or Ant,they can do all thing you want.

but, if you want to use them mixing, of course ,you can.
you can use maven-dependency-plugin in pom.xml to manage jar package.

search for detail information by google.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please be more clear? Is the jar you are talking about a non-open-source jar? In that case you should ("manually") add it to your central repository.
Otherwise find out in what central repository the jar is hosted, and add that to your repositories tag.

And just out of curiosity: why do you use Maven to manage dependencies and not Ivy?

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes, I'm using Maven to manage the project dependent jars, but I want use these jars when running build.xml.

Comment: @BradyChu You missed the point. Ivy is a dependency manager for ANT (Compatible with Maven repositories). See: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ Using ivy you don't need to mix build technologies. Another option is the aether ANT tasks, but I haven't used them: https://docs.sonatype.org/display/AETHER/Aether+Ant+Tasks